# Should questions using an existing tag that has a new SE site be flagged for migration?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration

There are many questions on Stack Overflow that ask about, in the case raising the question, using vi or Vim. Certainly, questions about programming plugins or extensions or syntax files would be on-topic for Stack Overflow, but questions about usage might be better migrated to vi.stackexchange.com, though that's still in beta.

Of course, its question rate may go up if Stack Overflow questions get migrated there.

Still, there is a history of asking such questions at Stack Overflow, so would it be appropriate to flag many, if not most, of the questions that are asked there as candidates for migrating to the new Stack Exchange site?

Also of note, the tag wiki does include the statement

> If your question is not about programming, consider posting Vim related questions at the dedicated Vim Stack Exchange site.

so it would seem the tag wiki would be in favor of such flags, or perhaps the flags are "too strong".

Comment: Sites often have overlap. If the post is on topic here, don't migrate.

Comment: 1) Keep in mind that questions over 60 days old cannot be migrated. 2) I believe mods try to avoid migrating to beta sites, to keep from artificially inflating the number of questions there before the site even gets going. Beta does not guarantee the site will live on to full release. 3) Just because it's on-topic on another site doesn't make it off-topic here. We don't migrate unless the question is high quality yet off-topic on the source site.

Comment: The tag wiki states that in order to let people know about the new site when they might not have known about it since it is a newer beta site.

Comment: @kendra good points of course, and I was not really meaning to go back and suggest migrating a lot of historical questions, mostly just new ones that come in that aren't really programming related.  Now that there is perhaps a better home for such questions, I was wondering if such new questions that are not about programming should be recommended for migration to the new site, but perhaps that would represent too much of a culture shift for questions that have no programming tie in, but have historically been answered there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because questions have been asked on SO which pertain to a new site does not mean that those questions should be immediately vacated to that site. Flagging these, especially en masse, will probably result in a stern message from a moderator asking you to not do that.

The new site will have a different topicality than Stack Overflow. As a result, migrating many, if not most, of the questions from Stack Overflow to the new site will cause a jarring effect since the topicality is going to be different.

If the questions had enough value and poise to remain on Stack Overflow then they should absolutely remain here as they were most likely on topic and helpful to the community.

If viable, the other site will generate questions related to its topicality at a rate which allows the new site to progress naturally.

Comment: Sure, and thanks.  I just find that many of the questions tagged with vi or vim are of questions that are the type likely to be generated by programmers, but not really programming questions, and thus might be better suited elsewhere, but I certainly acknowledge the concern about it being too disruptive to do it too widely, which is why I wanted to ask for opinions here